# Makes files using filenames stored in a textfile list

Tags: batch

I have inside a textfile a list of names like this

```
one.mkv
two three.mkv
four.five.mkv
six seven eight.avi
nine.mkv
ten eleven-twelve.mp4
```

Text file is called `list.txt`
I use this batch to try to make files

```
for /f "delims=" %F in (list.txt) do copy nul "%F"
```

but it doesn't create files. I want to create files exactly with names inside in that text list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not astoundingly clear but I'm assuming you want to create empty files. If so then the following will work from the command line:

```
for /f "delims=" %F in (list.txt) do type nul > "%F"
```

If you want it to work in a batch file then you need to replace `%F` with `%%F` like so:

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in (list.txt) do type nul > "%%F"
```

Comment: Thank you, it works !